# How to fix this "Invisible" syntax error in MySql query? (Using UPDATE inside TRIGGER)

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have the following MySQL query to create a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `updateParentLastInteractionOnInsert`
AFTER INSERT
ON `Post` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `Post` SET `lastInteraction` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = new.`parentPostId`;
END;
```

When I execute the query, I get the following error message:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

Since this means literally nothing, I've done my own research:

When I remove everything in the trigger's body (the statements between "BEGIN" and "END"), the query is processed successfully and an empty trigger is created.

So I've tested the inner statement by running the following query with a similar syntax:

```sql
UPDATE `Post` SET `lastInteraction` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `Post`.`id` = 1
```

which was also successfully executed.

I don't know what's wrong here. If both the trigger and the inner statements are syntactically & logically correct, how can the top query be syntactically incorrect? Maybe update statements aren't compatible with triggers? I've looked into MySql's documentation and around the web and I couldn't find any relevant information.

What's wrong in my query?

Comment: You probably forgot to use `DELIMITER`. Read this documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BillKarwin 's comment has the answer.

This works:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `updateParentLastInteractionOnInsert`
AFTER INSERT
ON `Post` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `Post` SET `lastInteraction` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = new.`parentPostId`;
END //
```

Comment: Once the syntax is sorted you will find that you cannot update the table which fired the trigger.